# Setup default temporal directories for CCompilerDriver

Tags: ccompilerdriver

Problem: 
I have cyrylic symbols in my `$UserBaseDirectory`. As result temporal directory for CreateExecutable`and friends is in my`$UserBaseDirectory`. Which produce error.

Code:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`"]

greeter = CreateExecutable[
  StringJoin["#include <stdio.h>\n", "int main(){\n", 
   "  printf(\"Hello MinGW-w64 world.\\n\");\n", "}\n"], "hiworld", 
  "Compiler" -> GenericCCompiler, 
  "CompilerInstallation" -> "C:/MinGW-64", 
  "CompilerName" -> "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe"
  ]
```

produce error

```
CreateExecutable::cmperr: Compile error: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\¦Ð¦\[Not]¦¦¦¦TÁ¦-¦-¦+TÀ\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\Working-pc6807-6420-5640-3\hiworld.c: No such file or directory >>
```

but

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`"]
greeter = CreateExecutable[
  StringJoin["#include <stdio.h>\n", "int main(){\n", 
   "  printf(\"Hello MinGW-w64 world.\\n\");\n", "}\n"], "hiworld", 
  "Compiler" -> GenericCCompiler, 
  "CompilerInstallation" -> "C:/MinGW-64", 
  "CompilerName" -> "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe",
  "WorkingDirectory"\[Rule]"c:\\1\\",
  "TargetDirectory"\[Rule]"c:\\2\\"
  ]
```

work fine.

Is there way to setup default value for "WorkingDirectory" and "TargetDirectory" for function like `CreateExecutable`?

Comment: It seems possible to use `SetOptions` for `CreateExecutable` as for other functions.  Have you tried that?:  ``SetOptions[CreateExecutable, "WorkingDirectory" -> "c:\\1\\", "TargetDirectory" -> "c:\\2\\"]``

Comment: @Mr.Wizard don't work

Comment: And you evaluated it after ``Needs["CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`"]``?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes.

Comment: Okay, I don't know why that would fail, and I haven't set up a C compiler yet so I can't test this.  I hope someone has a solution for you soon.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard anyway, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is undocumented function which return working (temporary) and target

```
CCompilerDirectories[]
(*{C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64,C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\Working}*)
```

`DownValues` of this function say that `$CCompilerDefaultDirectory` use for setup working and target directories

```
DownValues[CCompilerDirectories]
{HoldPattern[CCompilerDirectories[]]:>With[{CCompilerDriver`Private`target=$CCompilerDefaultDirectory},{CCompilerDriver`Private`target,FileNameJoin[{CCompilerDriver`Private`target,Working}]}]}
```

And then set `$CCompilerDefaultDirectory` as you wish.

PS:
easier way is to studie documentation

> $CCompilerDefaultDirectory  returns the default location for creating
>   output.

but we are not looking for easy ways =)